# Using Dot Syntax in Julia

Tags: julia

I have seen some code out in the wild that allows us to use dot syntax like so:

```
function dotTest!(wallet::Wallet, valueToAdd::Int):

...  

end

wallet = Wallet(100)

wallet.dotTest!(5)  # Does not work
dotTest!(wallet, 5)  # Works
```

However I cannot get it to work, the method is not found because I am not passing `wallet` as the arg.

So did the language change, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, in Julia `dot` never works like that.
but if you `using Lazy` then it is possible to write `@> wallet dotTest!(5)`

A related open discussion here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5571

Comment: I was wondering where the `Lazy.jl` functional magic (using macros) was at.  Much better than using `|>` .